# How to parse YouTube XML using Python?

Tags: python, xml, api, parsing

I am trying to parse the xml from YouTube that is embedded in the code below. I am trying to display all of the titles. However, I am running into trouble when I try to print the 'title' only enter lines appear. Any advice?

```
#import library to do http requests:
import urllib2

#import easy to use xml parser called minidom:
from xml.dom.minidom import parseString
#all these imports are standard on most modern python implementations

#download the file:
file = urllib2.urlopen('http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/buzzfeed/uploads?v=2&max-results=50')
#convert to string:
data = file.read()
#close file because we dont need it anymore:
file.close()

#parse the xml you downloaded
dom = parseString(data)
entry=dom.getElementsByTagName('entry')
for node in entry:
    video_title=node.getAttribute('title')
    print video_title
```

Comment: Please add an extract of the XML you want to parse.

Comment: Please, don't use `minidom`. The documentation tells you to use the [`ElementTree` API](http://docs.python.org/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html) instead. You can use the included version in the standard library, or use the excellent external [`lxml` library](http://lxml.de/) which expands on that API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Title is not an attribute, it is a child element of an entry.

here is an example how to extract it:

```
for node in entry:
    video_title = node.getElementsByTagName('title')[0].firstChild.nodeValue
    print video_title
```

Answer (score 0):

lxml can be a bit difficult to figure out, so here's a *really* simple beautiful soup solution (It's called beautifulsoup for a reason).  You can also set up beautiful soup to use the lxml parser, so the speed is about the same.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(data) # data as is seen in your code
soup.findAll('title')
```

returns a list of `title` elements.  you can also use `soup.findAll('media:title')` in this case to return just the `media:title` elements (the actual video names).

Answer (score 0):

There a small bug in your code. You access *title* as an attribute, although it's a child element of *entry*. Your code can be fixed by:

```
dom = parseString(data)
for node in dom.getElementsByTagName('entry'):
    print node.getElementsByTagName('title')[0].firstChild.data
```